# Get height of div and apply it to element within div

Tags: jquery, height, each

This seems like it should be very easy, and I've read a lot of the documentation, but can't seem to find an answer.

I have some nested divs, and I want to get the height of each div on the page and apply it to each of another div that's a child element.

I need to get the each-journal-image-container and apply it to each-journal-image-caption. There's multiple instances of this on the page, so an each() statement would best.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="each-journal-image-container clearfix">
    <div class="four columns">
      <div class="each-journal-image delay-1 animated fadeInLeftBig"></div>
      <div class="each-journal-image delay-1 animated fadeInLeftBig"></div>
      <div class="each-journal-image delay-1 animated fadeInLeftBig"></div>
      <div class="each-journal-image delay-1 animated fadeInLeftBig"></div>
      <div class="each-journal-image delay-1 animated fadeInLeftBig"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="two columns">
      <div class="each-journal-image-caption delay-2 animated fadeInLeftBig"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cheers,
R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortest solution I could think of:

```
$('.each-journal-image-container').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height();
    $(this).find('.each-journal-image-caption').height(h);
});
```

of course, you could combine the lines like this, but it's supposedly less efficient if you have 1000's of divs. If you have less than a hundred, the difference is negligible:

```
    $(this).find('.each-journal-image-caption').height($(this).height());
```

Comment: I thought this would work... but it's not taking the right height. Have a look? http://goo.gl/9dyB1 Thanks so far :)

Comment: Oh yes, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Maybe if I wrap it.

Comment: Wrapped it in a $(window).load(function() and works consistently now. Many thanks, Sam.

Answer (score 1):

use [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) attribute. It can be used to both: get the height and set the height of element.

```
$('.each-journal-image-container .four').height( $('.each-journal-image-container .two').height() );
```

Comment: I've been trying this, using different kinds of set up, but I can't seem to tackle it.

Comment: @rdck - see code sample. (ofq. it's just for containers - you need to loop through the correct elements to get the code you need)

Answer (score 0):

You would do this like so:

```
$('.each-journal-image-container').each(function(i,item){
    var height = $(item).height();
    $(this).find('.each-journal-image-caption').height(height);
});
```